# React-Native layout formatting for FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to list data on the screen in a side by side card style layout.    In a nutshell, I am trying to simulate is the float: left abilities with html and css.  Where each row contains two cards, which are just formatted View tags.  For some reason, they seems to display in a single column fashion all the way down the screen left justified instead.  What am I doing wrong with my stylesheet to make this vertical alignment issue occur?

```
screen.js:
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}>
<StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle="default" />
    <FlatList
data={myList}
renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={style.outerContainer}>
        <Image source={require('../../../../images/NoImageAvailable.png')} style={style.profileUrl} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={style.textContainer}>
                <Text style={style.mainHeading}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
)}
/>
</View>



style.js:
export default EStyleSheet.create({
    outerContainer: {
        width: 150,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: '#e9e9e9',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10
    },
    profileUrl: {
        width: 120,
        height: 120,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
    textContainer: {
        width: 120,
        height: 75,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: '#e9e9e9',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10
    },
    mainHeading: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight: '600'
    },
    bodyText: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to set two items of the flat-list side by side if so, have you tried setting  `numColumns={2}` to your flat list?

Or if you are talking about your Image and text, try setting `flexDirection` to your outerContainer.